# no file uploaded error in magento

Tags: magento, error-handling, magento-1.7

I have upgraded my Magento version from 1.4.0.1 to 1.7.0.2.

Now I tried to upload a theme package using upload package file in Magento Connect Manager. It shows an error 'No file was uploaded'.
Please get me a solution.

[image: Screen shot of the error]

Comment: there is no screenshot

Comment: The link to screenshot was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Version 2.0 from the dropdown on the extensionpage on magento-connect, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `No file was uploaded` error is return when:

- The form key is invalid
- `$_FILES` doesn't exist
- `$_FILES['file']` is empty

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to fix it by commenting out the rewrite instructions in my main `.htaccess` file in Magento's root folder. Don't forget to add those instructions back after you finished installing your module.

I suggest you keep a `.htaccess.magento-connect` file for when you want to use Magento Connect along with your regular `.htaccess` file, and switch between the two.